# Is there a way to hide elements without id or class in html using css?

Tags: html, css

So I have an issue with hiding nth element in a div which has no id but its parent div has an ID. I want to hide the 2nd span which says "second"

```
<div id="example">
  <div>
    <span>First</span>
    <span>Second</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try to address the inner div also by positional CSS selectors. Depends a little on how stable the structure is. In your case that could be `#example > div:first-child :nth-child( 2 )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can using: `nth-child()` property
Change the nth-child value to the span you want to hide - in this case 2 is the second span

```css
#example span:nth-child(2) { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <div>
    <span>First</span>
    <span>Second</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your question by checking the "check mark" under vote :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#example span:nth-of-type(2){
  display:none
}
```